# How to bind c++ objects as properties in objective-c?

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa-bindings, objective-c++

I would like to bind to Objective-C objects properties to each other, but the properties are c++ class. the property actually is a mathematical vector class, which is easier to work with since operator overload is quite useful with vector maths.
(I dont even see a good way working with vector math with objective-C objects, isthere?)

The problem is that binding this vector property crashes the app.
here is an example:

```
@interface M_Node : NSObject{
Vec3f pos;
M_Node *manipulator
}
@property Vec3f pos;
@end

@implementation
@synthesize pos;

@dynamic pos;
-(void)setPos:(Vec3f)newPos{
pos=Vec3f(newPos);
}
-(Vec3f)pos{
return Vec3f(pos);
}

- (id) init
{
self = [super init];
if (self != nil) {
[self bind:@"pos" toObject:self withKeyPath:@"manipulator.pos" options:nil];
}

return self;
}
```

the issue by Xcode:
Atomic property of type 'Vec3f' (aka 'Vec3') synthesizing setter using non-trivial assignment operator

I use the Vec3f class from cinder:
http://libcinder.org/docs/v0.8.3/classcinder_1_1_vec3.html

So the question is that how to bind c++ objects as properties in objective-c, or is it even possible? Is there another way to go?
(In case you have any idea how to do clean vector, matrix etc. math in objective-c please let me know.)

This is what I found in the documentation:

***KVC Conversion of Scalar and Structure Values**
The default implementations of the KVC methods valueForKey: and setValue:forKey: provide support for automatic object wrapping of scalar data types such as BOOL, char, double, float, int, and structures such as NSPoint, NSRange, and NSRect. When Cocoa scripting invokes valueForKey: to get a value, KVC automatically converts the value to an NSNumber object (for scalars) or NSValue object (for structures) if necessary.
Similarly, setValue:forKey: determines the data type required by the appropriate accessor or instance variable for the specified key. If the data type is not an object, then the value is extracted from the passed object using the appropriate NSNumber orNSValue method.
For more information, including a table of the supported types, see Scalar and Structure Support in Key-Value Coding Programming Guide*

Still, there are wrappers for structs like NSRect. There might be a way to override the original valueForKey: so it could also handle Vec3f.

So this would be the new question: **How to override the *valueForKey:* and *setValue: forKey:* so it would be able to handle my own c++ object?**

Comment: In the initializer, did you try putting the [self bind: etc... WITHIN the if (self != nil) block? Anything outside the block implies that self could be nil and the compiler will kick.

Comment: actually that was a typing error. The original is inside the if block. I even tried to bind two entirely seperate objects from outside. And it still crashes.

Comment: Have you tried implementing the setter yourself?

Comment: This is what I was working on right now, but still crashes.
I update the question and include the getter, setter.

Answer (score 1):

I very much doubt this will work.

Bindings is built on Key-Value Coding (KVC) and Key-Value Observing (KVO). You're using a key path of `manipulator.pos`. That means that the `manipulator` property must be an Objective-C object which is KVC- and KVO-compliant for the `pos` property. It's not clear, but I suspect that `M_Node` is a C++ class, not an Objective-C class, and therefore isn't KVC- or KVO-compliant for anything.

Next is the question of how KVC would return and pass the value of `pos` if it could get to it. KVC will wrap non-object data types in `NSNumber` or `NSValue` to pass them around. However, if a `Vec3f` is non-POD, then I doubt that will work well at all.

Ultimately, bindings isn't magic (although, admittedly, KVO has some near-magic isa-swizzling stuff in its implementation). The point is, would you expect that `[[yourObject valueForKey:@"manipulator"] valueForKey:@"pos"]` would work? Would you expect `[[yourObject valueForKey:@"manipulator"] setValue:someValue forKey:@"pos"]` to work? If not, then there's no chance bindings will work.

Comment: I have found a way that might would work. (actually stackoverflow does not allow me to answer my question yet, so I'll update it on the top.

Comment: I mentioned the idea you had but, for it to have a prayer of working, a `Vec3f` would have to be [POD (plain old data)](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/intrinsic-types.html#faq-26.7).

Comment: _“It's not clear, but I suspect that M_Node is a C++ class, not an Objective-C class”_  Nope, `M_Node` is clearly an Obj-C class.  See the very 1st line of the OP's code sample: `@interface M_Node : NSObject {`